# Can one use Tapestry Plastic with plain java (no groovy) without classcastexception

Tags: tapestry

Hi Tapestry plastic is a powerful framework that provides meta capabilities on class by modifying bytecode on the fly thanks a beautiful dsl.

http://tawus.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/meeting-plastic/

However in all samples and test tapestry folks use groovy... I want to use it with java but I never manage to do so because of ClassCastException on the generated object ? I know this is is a classloader issue but what is the trick ?

Can we use tapestry plastic with plain java and outside tapestry web framework ?

```
     ...
     PlasticManager pm = PlasticManager.withContextClassLoader().packages (  Arrays.asList( "plastic" )).
     delegate(new StandardDelegate(new ToStringTransformer())).create();


     Foo foo = (Foo) pm.getClassInstantiator("plastic.controlled.Foo").newInstance();

     ...
```

This returns a ClassCastException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use Plastic with Java. That is how it is being used in Tapestry core. In java you have to do something like

```
Object foo = pm.getClassInstantiator("plastic.controlled.Foo").newInstance()
```

You are getting a `ClassCastException` because you are trying to put a transformed class into a Foo class. The transformed class is not inherited from the original class and so can't be casted into it.

When you access the instance using `Object` you can only access `Object` methods like `toString()`, `equals()` etc which is obviously very limiting. The trick here is to use an interface/implementation pattern. You can have controlled classes implement the given interface and then you can access the new object using that interface.

```
MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface)pm.getClassInstantiator(
    "plastic.controlled.Foo").newInstance()
```

Checkout the other tutorials on my blog so see how that is done.

Hope it helps!

Comment: No code, so can't help much. But remember when working with interfaces you have to implement the interface using PlasticClass#introduceInterface. Run through the different blog posts [Java Magic](http://tawus.wordpress.com/tag/plastic-2/) to find an example.

Comment: BTW If you will explain what you are trying to achieve with plastic may be I can help better :)

Comment: Thx @Tawus, ClassCastException disapears but I get 
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Method toString in class plastic/controlled/MyInterface has illegal modifiers: 0x1 

Can you give me again  the right interface to implement ?

PS : I got issues with my previous comment so I deleted it.

Comment: Hi Tawus, it is understood now, I manage to get the sample working in java , thank you again.